# Vega-Lite Dynamic Label Width (Reactive Geometry)

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I am creating a timeline bar chart that has labels on the bars. Currently, the labels will go outside of the bar and overlap with others. I am looking to capture the width of a bar so I can use that for the label width limit to cut off anything outside of the bar.

[image]

[Vega Code](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoHHABOM+egCCwqHEUgkUTDWJ0AnmhAAVM0lJhWTJHCHUzTG8AJgAGKIAWfjikqJ8YsVQAZhjUGJjHOFllaLjE5Li0gDYsnLyQAF8FE3NLb1sae0dnV3dML3QAdTYzAGsaYNDwyPRYhJSUtIB2XNr8pULimdL5ioBGKJWVhqaQUws5NrsHJW63T28AGQZZWEmkCJK58tT9mqP1oqfMpRBa7TKHOqNZrnKwgdqdG4uO59bwAITMcCQI2UbAA7vIlGF3tMQLNgaD4hC1iANkCdj9KdkjlDTi0LuhUWwmF0kb1+iAhqNxiFCVM6d8qlSCoCtl8QXtdn9ISczq0OVyeT17ugALJIcaYQpIF7XEBEj6y8l7A55f40mWk7YSsFK-Is1XskCc7mIrUo9AABQx-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-SgI101xh627tfxICyGwCDjH1NwDUNdF0GNgYtgYc20bxHjmOxIDFSM9X7Vl7zHPalXVUtEmCMM9Vbc13h5vcShfegR0nbIZ1mlZ-GgDiyDjEYvj+IE1VKIWuM9s8rxKOuWI4vijh6gaRomo4QZwCGYZKOBj7FIVIAMWQ-GGCAADEuxMYsixMPEji80xgtMTEpq81EnFxFAYvKJUUSLFEAAcYsAJzxJUwvPnz6tQGIlTxD6fNwJkQtQGFNFKI5XMyrIPGCA9JzvZ9HgdeghryZENzCGQsKOUx-sqHVWRKMo-S7EopkQNN4wHSdyjKGNSgsbImAAMo0AAXvxWv25NdD1XA8k4GY0VeSl2W5fQem-dNwh4IN3jKU3LxsFVExLb70ybStENdiiD00UAA)

I did find a possibly working solution on this site: https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/deneb-limit-data-label-width/32850
[image]

Unfortunately the did not explain the full solution, and I've been unable to figure it out. I'm unsure what concat_0_x contains or how to reproduce it. I've tried the Vega documentation on scale and looking for usage examples but haven't been able to figure out a way to find the bar width.

If someone could help fill in the gaps from the above solution or provide another method of obtaining the bar width so I can use it as the width limit, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "person": "Alice",
        "activity": "Traveling",
        "start": "2024-02-02T05:30:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T06:30:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Alice",
        "activity": "Working",
        "start": "2024-02-02T07:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T12:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Alice",
        "activity": "Lunch",
        "start": "2024-02-02T12:30:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T13:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Alice",
        "activity": "Breakdown",
        "start": "2024-02-02T14:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T14:30:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Bob",
        "activity": "Working",
        "start": "2024-02-02T06:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T11:30:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Bob",
        "activity": "Maintenance",
        "start": "2024-02-02T12:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T13:30:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Bob",
        "activity": "Pre-op",
        "start": "2024-02-02T14:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T15:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Charlie",
        "activity": "Working",
        "start": "2024-02-02T06:30:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T11:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Charlie",
        "activity": "Lunch",
        "start": "2024-02-02T11:30:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T12:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Charlie",
        "activity": "Breakdown",
        "start": "2024-02-02T14:30:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T15:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Alice",
        "activity": "Parked",
        "start": "2024-02-02T15:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T17:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Bob",
        "activity": "Parked",
        "start": "2024-02-02T15:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T17:00:00"
      },
      {
        "person": "Charlie",
        "activity": "Parked",
        "start": "2024-02-02T15:00:00",
        "end": "2024-02-02T17:00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "start",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": "Timeline"}
        },
        "x2": {"field": "end"},
        "y": {
          "field": "person",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "Persons"}
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "activity",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "Traveling",
              "Working",
              "Lunch",
              "Breakdown",
              "Maintenance",
              "Pre-op",
              "Parked"
            ],
            "range": [
              "#1f77b4",
              "#ff7f0e",
              "#2ca02c",
              "#d62728",
              "#9467bd",
              "#8c564b",
              "#e377c2"
            ]
          },
          "legend": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "scale('layer_0_x', datum['end']) - scale('layer_0_x', datum['start'])", "as": "testLength"}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "dx": 3,
        "dy": 1,
        "baseline": "middle",
        "fontSize": 9,
        "limit": {"expr": "datum['testLength'] - 2"},
        "ellipsis": " ",
        "x": {"expr": "scale('layer_0_x',datum.start)"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "activity"},
        "y": {
          "field": "person",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "Persons"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: This works great. I've been struggling with this for days. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. This is a bit of a hack and if you want more advanced functionality, you're best looking at Vega. There is a similar chart to yours implemented in Vega here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: What would be nice is to add ".." at the end if the label is being truncated.